# c# return loop without using foreach

Tags: c#

Hello I need some help in my Code
Code in test.cs:

```
public class test
    {
        public string[] content ={
                    "Username:Peter",
                    "ID:1",
                    "Username:Nike",
                    "ID:2"};
        public IEnumerable<string> Name
        {
            get
            {
                var username = content.Where(a => a.StartsWith("Username:")).ToList();
                for(int i = 0; i < username.Count(); i++)
                {
                    yield return username[i].Substring(username[i].IndexOf(":") +1); // Displays the usernames (Peter, Nike)
                }
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<string> ID
        {
            get
            {
                var username = content.Where(a => a.StartsWith("ID:")).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < username.Count(); i++)
                {
                    yield return username[i].Substring(username[i].IndexOf(":") +1); // Displays the ID (1, 2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code in main file:

```
var test = new test();
foreach (var l in test.Name)
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(l);
```

All works fine it displays the names right, but I dont want use foreach i want add it like:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Name: " + test.Name + " ID:" + test.ID);
```

thanxs for helping

Comment: Something like `treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(test.Name)` ?

Comment: cant convert IEnumerable<string> in TreeNode[]

Comment: With the data you're showing, you're expecting your treeView to have 2 nodes?  The treeView1.Nodes.Add() is meant for adding ONE node.

Comment: But  in test.cs is already the loop

Comment: Are you wanting the node to look like "Name: Peter, Nike ID:1, 2"?

Comment: This with treeview is currently not important, I want it to be output as a string but only with `test.Name test.ID`

Comment: You have failed to answer both of my questions, so I will ask it like this.  With the data you show in your question, what is the expected result?  Not what code you want to try, what is supposed to be outputted?

Comment: @Dave In it's current form, it's not suited for anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to `array` and then use a `for` loop (assuming you're sure that elements are in pairs):

```
var names = test.Name.ToArray();
var ids = test.Id.ToArray();

for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add("Name: " + names[i] + " ID: " + ids[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want it to look that way   
`treeView1.Nodes.Add("Name: " + test.Name + " ID:" + test.ID);`

Answer (score 0):

firstly:

```
public class test
{
    public string[] content ={
        "Username:Peter",
        "ID:1",
        "Username:Nike",
        "ID:2"};

    public Dictionary<string, string> contents;

    public Dictionary<string, string> Contents
    {
        get
        {
            if (contents == null)
            {
                InitContents();
            }

            return contents;
        }
    }

    private void InitContents()
    {
        contents = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
        {
            contents.Add(GetValue(content[i]), GetValue(content[i + 1]));
            i++;
        }
    }

    private string GetValue(string data)
    {
        return data.Substring(data.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetContents()
    {
        return Contents.Select(x => "Name: " + x.Key + " ID:" + x.Value);
    }


}
```

then use:

```
treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(yourTests.Contents.Select(x=>new TreeNode("Name:"+x.Key+"Id:"+x.Value))))
```

Comment: I guess your content array is from some api response, but it's not formatted to strong type code. here i use dictionary to massage it, but it should be a model(contains: UserName, Id, ...) if it has more fields. BTW, you naming confused me, "Name" should be "Names" or "UserNames", "ID" should be "UserIds" or "IDs"

Comment: BTW, the "content" array should be converted to strong type immediately once it's responded. then you can return whatever data structure from your strong-typed objects